# Get the current UIScrollView scroll values on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

If I have a `UIScrollView` and move it around to a specific location, is there any way to get that position it has moved too?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Check UIScrollView's contentOffset property:

> **contentOffset** - The point at which the origin of the content view is
>   offset from the origin of the scroll
>   view.

By implementing and setting UIScrollView's delegate you can also handle numerous scrolling/zooming events in UIScrollView.