# how to set current scrolling values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

If I have a UIScrollView and move it around to a specific location, is there any way to get that position it has moved too?

Comment: please ask more specific what exactly you want?

Answer (score 1):

> Check UIScrollView's contentOffset property:
>
> contentOffset - The point at which the origin of the content view is offset from the origin of the scroll view.

[Get the current UIScrollView scroll values on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448983/get-the-current-uiscrollview-scroll-values-on-the-iphone=)