# Is it possible to get the tableview scroll direction and get the bottom most cell's indexpath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Hi is it possible to get the tableview scroll direction? Is the scroll is up scroll or down scroll?  Because i need to get the bottom most cell's indexpath.row and store it to a variable.

If not then please give me any suggestion how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can confirm to protocol UITableViewDelegate and implement the -scrollViewDidScroll method. This method called whenever user scrolls the tableView.

Also you can check the contentOffset of scrollView and compare it with the last one.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFlaot lastContentOffset

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > self.lastContentOffset.y) {
        // Scroll down direction 
    } else {
        // Scroll to up
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = currentOffset;
}
```

And do not forget to set tableViewDelegate

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to know is the scrollView is moving up or down, you can use this

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let translation = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview!)
    if translation.y > 0 {
        print("scrolling down")
    } else {
        print("scrolling up")
    }
}
```

Remember to set `scrollView.delegate = self` in your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Make your class the delegate of the tableview, then override `scrollViewDidScroll`.

You'll have to keep track of the previous scroll position yourself, but you can do that by querying the scrollview's content offset: [Get the current UIScrollView scroll values on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448983/get-the-current-uiscrollview-scroll-values-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it is possible ! As `tableView` is inherited from `scrollView` you are allowed to use  `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

- Add `UIScrollViewDelegate` .
- Now implement any of these delegate functions `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop` , `scrollViewDidScroll` . And now you can track moving of your `tableView`  by comparing `tableView`'s `X - Position`

**Example Implementation of Delegate Function :**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) 
{
    if scrollView == tableView // incase you have multiple scrollViews
    {
         print(scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as below.

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                    withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
             targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{

    if (velocity.y > 0){
        NSLog(@"scrolling up");
    }
    if (velocity.y < 0){
        NSLog(@"scrolling down");
    }
}
```